# Powershell how to use "Add-Type NamePresentationFramework" in .PS script?

Tags: powershell

if I type this on the command line:

```
Add-Type NamePresentationFramework
```

I can then call this in a Powershell script:

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Would  you like to play a game?','Game input','YesNoCancel','Error')
```

My question is, how would I add the NamePresentationFramework within a script itself?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your script by adding the `Add-Type` in there. The assembly name to use ir `PresentationFramework`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Would  you like to play a game?','Game input','YesNoCancel','Question')
```